# group in aggregate framework stopped working properly

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I hate this kind of questions but maybe you can point me to obvious. I'm using Mongo 2.2.2.

I have a collection (in replica set) with 6M documents which has string field called *username* on which I have index. The index was non-unique but recently I made it unique. Suddenly following query gives me false alarms that I have duplicates.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $group : {_id : "$username", total : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $match : { total : { $gte : 2 } } },
    { $sort : {total : -1} } );
```

which returns

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "davidbeges",
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "jesusantonio",
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "elesitasweet",
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "theschoolofbmx",
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "longflight",
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "thenotoriouscma",
                        "total" : 2
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I tested this query on sample collection with few documents and it works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that unique index was successfully created?  If there are existing dups it will fail to create unless you set the `dropDups: true` option.  See [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#drop-duplicates).

Comment: Yes. I can see that there is only one document when I query `db.users.find({username : "thenotoriouscma"})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of 10gen responded in their JIRA.

*Are there any updates on this collection? If so, I'd try adding {$sort: {username:1}} to the front of the pipeline. That will ensure that you only see each username once if it is unique.
If there are updates going on, it is possible that aggregation would see a document twice if it moves due to growth. Another possibility is that a document was deleted after being seen by the aggregation and a new one was inserted with the same username.*

So sorting by `username` before grouping helped.

Comment: +1 ah, so I wasn't far off - the issue is the table scan versus an index - the index ensures that the doc is only seen once, a table scan does not, and they are seen twice - by adding the `$sort` you use the index and avoid the problem with the `$group`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may lie in the fact that your `$group` is not using an index, it's just doing a scan over the entire collection.  These operators can use and index currently in the aggregation framework:

```
$match $sort $limit $skip
```

And they will work if placed before:

```
$project $unwind $group
```

However, `$group` by itself will not use an index.  When you do your `find()` test I am betting you are using the index, possibly as a covered index (you can verify by looking at an `explain()` for that query), rather than scanning the collection.  Basically my theory is that your index has no dupes, but your collection does.

Edit: This likely happens because a document is updated/moved during the aggregation operation and hence is seen twice, not because of dupes in the collection as originally thought.

If you add an operator earlier in the pipeline that can use the index but not alter the results fed into `$group`, then you can avoid the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately find without index returned one document as well :( Also side note, I wouldn't be able to create unique index unless I drop the dups.

Comment: Dang.....you may have a bug then, which would be worth filing at http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER - it would potentially be hard to reproduce without the actual data, especially since you mention it works as expected with test data - can you sanitize it perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I'm concerned bug may disappear as I noticed list of phantom documents is different today. I filed `SERVER-7930`. Could you tell me how I can save the data so you guys can reproduce it if necessary? Will `mongodump` suffice?

Comment: Edited so my answer makes more sense and doesn't cause any confusion :)